# Can you reset private mode on a Samsung Galaxy S5?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, private-mode

I set up private mode when I first got the phone, but now I can't seem to remember the password; it's none of my usual ones. Is it possible to reset (read: wipe) private mode and start over, without having to factory reset the whole phone?

I have root, if that helps.

Comment: No you can't reset the Private mode password. Only way is to reset the Phone. Read more on [this androidforum thread](http://androidforums.com/threads/private-mode.842799/)

Comment: @Lucky I don't mind about the content of private mode, I can reset it if necessary, but I would like to avoid to reset the whole phone... Maybe there's a way to do this? It's something different from just resetting the private mode password, as it would lead to the loss of the private mode content

Comment: I'm not surprised the only option is resetting the phone entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install **Samsung Kies** on your PC? Try to download it, connect your device and click the Backup/reset tab, and then click "Data backup".

The easiest way it factory reset. If you have any private data who you don't want to loose say what sort is it, there are numerous ways to backup them.

Comment: Is there a way to reset just the private mode content (and password) instead of the whole phone? I don't mind about the content I had previously protected, I have a copy of it, I would just like to be able to use private mode again

Comment: You'll be able to use private mode after factory reset. But there is no know solution to reset private mode without the reset.

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping the Dalvik/ART Cache (as you are on root, you can boot into any custom recovery tool and perform this).
This resets the settings without wiping the data. So you can setup the private mode from the beginning.